# Proper way to update Docker image in Kubernetes manifest file using Azure Pipelines

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have successfully built and pushed a docker image to Docker Hub using the Docker task using Azure Pipelines.

Now I would like to take that Docker image and deploy it to my Kubernetes cluster in AKS.

I need to update the image by using `kubectl apply`. I need to use `kubectl apply` specifically and not `replace`, `edit`, or `patch`.

How can I achieve that while also updating `spec.containers.image` in my deploy.yml file?

**I basically want to take this variable `tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'`, replace `spec.containers.image` in deploy.yml and then run kubectl apply -f deploy.yml.**

Here's my deploy.yml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myprojectname
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app: myprojectname
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      web: myprojectname
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myprojectname
        web: myprojectname
        type: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myprojectname
          image: mydockerhubaccount/myprojectname:25
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 20m
              memory: 100Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 130Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

Here's my azure-pipelines.yml file:

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'Docker Hub'
  imageRepository: 'mydockerhubaccount/myprojectname'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/my-project-name/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
        buildContext: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be an old question but is still relevant today. The process is mostly the same for the "classic" visual DevOps pipeline builder as it is for the YAML step builder.

Generally speaking, the way to update the container image tag with the current build (without using "latest" to enable rollbacks) is as follows:

1. In the release pipeline make note of your Artifact `Source Alias`. The artifact being the result from your build process. If your build process doesn't publish an artifact, add the default: `Publish Pipeline Artifact` step. You can call the source alias whatever you like as long as it is unique and spaces are not important.
2. In your Release Pipeline's Stages for `Deploy to Kubernetes` select the correct manifest.
3. Then update the `Containers` field to the name of your container repo and add `$(Release.Artifacts.YOUR_SOURCE_ALIAS_HERE.BuildId)` as the tag. It should looks something like: `YOUR_REPO.azurecr.io/YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME:$(Release.Artifacts.YOUR_SOURCE_ALIAS_HERE.BuildId)`
4. When the pipeline deploys to K8 it should be using the latest tag id from your build process. You can confirm this on your cluster by describing your pod/whatever with something like: `kubectl describe pod POD_NAME`

**Example YAML deployment step:**

```
steps:
- task: KubernetesManifest@0
  displayName: deploy
  inputs:
    kubernetesServiceConnection: 'YOUR_CONNECTION'
    namespace: 'CLUSTER_NAMEPACE'
    manifests: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/YOUR_SOURCE_ALIAS_HERE/Job1/s/whatever-deployment.yml'
    containers: 'YOUR_REPO.azurecr.io/YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME:$(Release.Artifacts.YOUR_SOURCE_ALIAS_HERE.BuildId)'
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to inject the docker image name and version into the `deployment.yml`, you should first have to create a placeholder for it. For example in this deployment manifest file example:

```
apiVersion : apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <your_k8s_deployment_name>
  namespace: <your_k8s_namespace>
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: <your_k8s_namespace>
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: <your_k8s_namespace>
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 1000
      containers:
        - name: <your_k8s_namespace>
          image: {{DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}}:{{DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION}}
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8501
```

The placeholders are the `DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME` and the `DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION` variable. Next, you need to update these variables inside the `azure-pipelines.yml` file. Here is the content snippet of the Azure pipeline file:

```
variables:
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: <your_docker_registry_svc>
  imagePullSecret: <your_imgpull_secret>
  containerRegistryURL: <your_container_registry>.azurecr.io
  imageRepository: <your_image_repository>
  tag: <your_docker_version_tag>
  kubernetesServiceConnection: <your_k8s_svc>
  kubernetesNameSpace: <your_k8s_namespace>
  deploymentPath: <your_manifest_path>
  vmImageName: ubuntu-latest

--- snip ---

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: KubernetesManifest@1
      displayName: Create imagePullSecret
      inputs:
        action: createSecret
        kubernetesServiceConnection: $(kubernetesServiceConnection)
        namespace: $(kubernetesNameSpace)
        secretName: $(imagePullSecret)
        dockerRegistryEndpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
    - script: |
        sed -i "s|{{DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}}|$(containerRegistryURL)/$(imageRepository)|g" $(deploymentPath)
        sed -i "s|{{DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION}}|$(tag)|g" $(deploymentPath)
      displayName: 'Replace Docker image name and version in deployment manifest file'
    - task: KubernetesManifest@1
      displayName: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
      inputs:
        action: deploy
        kubernetesServiceConnection: $(kubernetesServiceConnection)
        namespace: $(kubernetesNameSpace)
        imagePullSecrets: $(imagePullSecret) 
        manifests: $(deploymentPath)
        containers: $(containerRegistryURL)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)
        rolloutStatusTimeout: 60
```

As you can see the variables are set by using the `sed` Linux command. Do **not** forget to update your variables accordingly.

> Note: I am using multi-stage deployment hence the `dependsOn` parameter is used. If you do not want a multi-stage pipeline then remove the stages and the `dependsOn` parameter as well.